# Understanding \add@unicode@accent and renewing it for conjoining diacritics

Tags: unicode

I recently came to know about the command `\DeclareUnicodeAccent` which can declare a diacritic which is printed *after* the argument of the declared command. e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}
\DeclareUnicodeAccent{\foo}{TU}{"031F} % ̟

\begin{document}
\foo{b}
\end{document}
```

produces `b̟` -

[image: 1]

Now I want a similar command for conjoining diacritics. It should declare the command in such a way that the diacritic will be placed between the first and the second character of its argument. A dummy (not working) code is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CharisSIL}
\DeclareUnicodeConjoiningDiacritic{\bar}{TU}{"0361} % ͡

\begin{document}
\bar{ab}
\end{document}
```

Shall produce `a͡b` -

[image: 2]

In [`source2e.pdf`](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e) I found the following definition for `\DeclareUnicodeAccent` (which was quite easy to understand), but I didn't understand the definition of `\add@unicode@accent` which must be renewed in order to produce the results correctly.

```
\def\add@unicode@accent#1#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax^^a0\else#2\fi
  \char#1\relax}
\def\DeclareUnicodeAccent#1#2#3{%
  \DeclareTextCommand{#1}{#2}{\add@unicode@accent{#3}}%
}
```

I want to understand what `\add@unicode@accent` exactly does and how to renew it for the command that I want to develop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}

\NewDocumentCommand{\conjoining}{m >{\SplitArgument{1}{}}m}{%
  \makeconjoining{#1}#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeconjoining}{mmm}{%
  #2\symbol{"#1}#3%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\doubleinvertedbreve}{m}{%
  \conjoining{0361}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\doubleinvertedbreve{ab}
\doubleinvertedbreve{AB}
\doubleinvertedbreve{aB}
\doubleinvertedbreve{Ax}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What does `\DeclareUnicodeAccent` do?

```
\def\DeclareUnicodeAccent#1#2#3{%
  \DeclareTextCommand{#1}{#2}{\add@unicode@accent{#3}}%
}
```

It is an interface to `\DeclareTextCommand`, so

```
\DeclareUnicodeAccent{\foo}{TU}{<number>}
```

is the same as

```
\DeclareTextCommand{\foo}{TU}{\add@unicode@accent{<number>}}
```

Hence, if the current encoding is `TU`, the command `\foo{x}` will do

```
\add@unicode@accent{<number>}{x}
```

and the definition of `\add@unicode@accent` is very simple:

```
\def\add@unicode@accent#1#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax^^a0\else#2\fi
  \char#1\relax}
```

which means that if the second argument is empty, the character U+00A0 is inserted, followed by `\char<number>\relax`.

It simply isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I really want to know the working of `\add@unicode@accent` command. Your answer produces the correct visual output, but doesn't really explain the working of the desired command.

Comment: @Niranjan You *don't* want to use that command, I believe.

Comment: I want to develope the command given in the dummy code i.e. `\DeclareUnicodeConjoiningDiacritic` with the same method that LaTeX sources use and the working of `\add@unicode@accent` is a bit complicated to understand for me, but I want to keep my new definition as close to the core LaTeX commands as possible.

Comment: @Niranjan I added a description, from which it follows that it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Niranjan it would be easier if you wouldn't require that the two chars around the accent are in the argument. Something like a\conjoin b would be easier and would then also work e.g. in bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, your answer works for me. I have ran into a different problem with this code, but it is unrelated here, I'll post another question for it :)

Answer (score 2):

A small modification of the answer by egreg to lower the accent in case both letters are small (i.e., no ascenders). It works by measuring the height of the argument and calculating the difference between this height and the height of the combination AX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{calc}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\newdimen\conjh
\newdimen\upperh
\NewDocumentCommand{\conjoining}{m >{\SplitArgument{1}{}}m}{%
  \makeconjoining{#1}#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeconjoining}{mmm}{%
  \settoheight{\upperh}{AX}%
  \settoheight{\conjh}{#2#3}%
  #2\raisebox{\conjh-\upperh}{\symbol{"#1}}#3%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\doubleinvertedbreve}{m}{%
  \conjoining{0361}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\doubleinvertedbreve{ab}
\doubleinvertedbreve{AB}
\doubleinvertedbreve{aB}
\doubleinvertedbreve{Ax}
\doubleinvertedbreve{ax}

\Huge
\doubleinvertedbreve{ab}
\doubleinvertedbreve{AB}
\doubleinvertedbreve{aB}
\doubleinvertedbreve{Ax}
\doubleinvertedbreve{ax}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I really want to know the working of `\add@unicode@accent` command. Your answer produces the correct visual output, but doesn't really explain the working of the desired command.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do at TeX primitive level looks like this:

```
\def\bar#1{\barA#1}
\def\barA#1#2{\setbox0=\hbox{#1#2}\dimen0=\ht0
   \ifdim\dimen0>1ex \advance\dimen0 by-1ex \else \dimen0=0pt \fi
   #1\raise\dimen0\hbox{\char"0361}#2%
}  

\bar{aB}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I really wanted to know the working of \add@unicode@accent command. egreg's answer explains it.